# Como popular o AlertDialog no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Estou tomando uma porrada aqui do Java e do Android Studio.

- Eu já criei uma Activity + DialogFragment, as informações de location não passam da tela Activity para o DialogFragment!
- Agora estou tentando fazer um AlertDialog dentro da Activity para ver se eu consigo utilizar a latitude e longitude do gps do usuário. Porém ao clicar no botão ele da erro e fecha o aplicativo.

Como faço para popular essas informações dentro deste alert dialog?

**AboutScreen.java**

```
/*===============================================================================
Copyright (c) 2016 PTC Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Qualcomm Connected Experiences, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Vuforia is a trademark of PTC Inc., registered in the United States and other 
countries.
===============================================================================*/

package com.vuforia.samples.Books.ui.ActivityList;

import com.vuforia.samples.Books.R;
import com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Books.Books;
import com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Neoris.Shopping;
import android.Manifest;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AboutScreen extends FragmentActivity {

    private Button mStartButton;
    private String mClassToLaunch;
    private String mClassToLaunchPackage;

    private TextView txtShoppingName;
    private TextView txtShoppingCity;
    private TextView txtShoppingLat;
    private TextView txtShoppingLong;

    private Location location;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Address endereco;

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about_screen);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mClassToLaunchPackage = getPackageName();
        mClassToLaunch = mClassToLaunchPackage + "." + extras.getString("ACTIVITY_TO_LAUNCH");

        /**
         * VERIFICAÇÃO DA PERMISSÃO DO USUÁRIO AO USO DO GPS
         */

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        } else {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }

        if (location !=null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        txtShoppingName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtShoppingName);
        txtShoppingCity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtShoppingCity);
        txtShoppingLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtShoppingLat);
        txtShoppingLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtShoppingLong);

        mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);
        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //Cria um Layout para o DialogFragment.
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AboutScreen.this);
                AboutScreen abs = new AboutScreen();
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialogo, null);

                ImageView mImageTitle = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
                TextView  mShoppingName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.shoppingName);
                TextView  mShoppingCity = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.shoppingCity);
                Button mComecarButton = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_comecar);

                //Insere as Informações ao Dialogo.
                txtShoppingLat.setText(" " + latitude);
                txtShoppingLong.setText(" " + longitude);


                //Abre a Activity Books.
                mComecarButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(AboutScreen.this, Books.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

    }



}
```

**AlertFragmentLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImageTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/blue_aliansce"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTitle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/world_location"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shoppingName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="SHOPPING:"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/backgroundImageTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shoppingCity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="CIDADE:"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/shoppingName"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/shoppingName"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/shoppingName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shoppingLat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="LATITUDE:"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/shoppingCity"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/shoppingCity"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/shoppingCity" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shoppingLong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="LONGITUDE:"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/shoppingLat"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/shoppingLat"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/shoppingLat" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_comecar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green_aliansce"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="@dimen/menu_title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/btn_comecar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/shoppingLong"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtShoppingName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/shoppingName"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageTitle"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageTitle"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/shoppingName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtShoppingCity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/shoppingLat"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtShoppingName"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtShoppingName"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/shoppingCity" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtShoppingLat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/shoppingLong"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtShoppingCity"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtShoppingCity"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/shoppingLat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtShoppingLong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtShoppingLat"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtShoppingLat"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/shoppingLong"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_comecar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ERRO**

> 06-14 15:12:17.818 11356-11356/com.vuforia.samples.Books
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.vuforia.samples.Books, PID: 11356
>                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                  at
>   com.vuforia.samples.Books.ui.ActivityList.AboutScreen$1.onClick(AboutScreen.java:104)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5340)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21610)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo erro, alguma TextView sua não foi encontrada corretamente pelo respectivo findViewById no Java. Tem que debugar e ver qual é (a que retornar nulo para a variável). No mais seu layout tem views com ids repetidos, além de algumas views estarem usando alinhamento referenciando outras views com "@+id" (deveria ser apenas "@id", pois o + é usado apenas para criar um id novo na hierarquia de views e atribuí-lo a uma view) e isso também pode causar problemas.

Comment: Não há problema em usar sempre `@+id`, se o id já existir não será criado outro, é como se tivesse utilizado `@id`.